# java.util.zip.ZipException in Glassfish (v3) application deployment

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I've got a strange exception with my EJB3.1 application, a `ZipException` is thrown during the application deployment:

```
[#|2010-05-15T16:01:44.688+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.org.glassfish.web.loader|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|WEB9051: Error trying to scan the classes at /Users/kevin/Documents/netbeans/WebAlbums/trunk/WebAlbums3/WebAlbums3-ea/dist/gfdeploy/WebAlbums3-Service.jar for annotations in which a ServletContainerInitializer has expressed interest
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:133)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.ServletContainerInitializerUtil.getInitializerList(ServletContainerInitializerUtil.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
|#]
```

I don't really know how to investigate this error; I know that it's not related to the Glassfish installation (same problem on Ubuntu and Mac).

---

*EDIT:*
(the classpath details seem to be useless)

the problem with .../WebAlbums3-ea/dist/gfdeploy/WebAlbums3-Service.jar is that this file is not actually present where Glassfish is looking for it ...
Instead, I've got a *folder* named WebAlbums3-Service_jar

---

(I'm using Netbeans 6.8, Glassfish v3, Servlet3, EJB 3.1, JPA/Hibernate)

Thank you for your help

*EDIT:* The issue (both ZipException and already loaded EJBs) was resolved by extracting the EJB interfaces outside of where the implementation was defined (the implementation classes were loaded with each of the modules, hence the EJB exception)

Comment: For what it's worth, I get a similar exception every now and then deploying under SpringSource dm Server.  Does this happen always or just sometimes?

Comment: no, it's really for all my deployments

Comment: Having an '_' instead of a '.' is normal when you use exploded deployment (that's how the exploded artifact is supposed to be deployed).

Comment: Could this happen if GlassFish starts deploying before the file has finished being copied in?  A slow upload?

Comment: @Thorbjørn no, I don't think so, it really happens all the time, even if the building was finished long time before

Comment: First of all, validate the jar file with "unzip -t".  It might actually be broken!

Comment: no, no, take a look at the other answsers/comments, it's not a jar, it's a folder which is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen several mentions of this problem on the web like [this one](http://java.dzone.com/articles/glassfish-3-30-minutes) that mentions it as non blocking:

> If you get the following error after deploying the EAR, don't worry, it's quite normal: "WEB9051: Error trying to scan the classes at .../eclipseApps/Seven/SevenEJB.jar for annotations in which a ServletContainerInitializer has expressed interest". See here.

And also in [Issue 11149](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11149) or [Issue 11341](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11341). Your case seems to be different but if it's not (if you have a jar with a '+' in the file name) it should be fixed in GF v3.0.1.

If this doesn't apply to you, I suggest [creating an issue](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectIssues). Even if non blocking, this is clearly not normal.

Comment: There is no + in the jar names so that's different indeed, and it's non blocking as well in my case. I've raised the <a href="https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11911">issue 11911</a>.  Thank you!

Comment: hum, how am I supposed to deploy manually my ea-project? when I deploy the EAR, I got an exception (2 ejbs with the same interface -- not true, I mean it's a packaging problem), whereas Netbeans' deploy?path=.../WebAlbums3-ea/dist/gfdeploy is ok  (I wanted to join this EAR with the issue report)

Comment: @Kevin the easiest way is to copy it to the `autodeploy` directory of your domain.

Comment: no, it's the same problem, the EJBs are seen as 'duplicated', (Servlet->Service->DAO) EJBs in DAO will be seen 3 times, and those in Service twice ...

Comment: @Kevin Are you sure the "netbeans" code has been undeployed? What do you see in GlassFish admin console under "Applications"?

Comment: @Pascal, yes I'm sure, I've just undeployed everything, the same exception occurs again ...

Answer (score 1):

> Error trying to scan the classes at /Users/kevin/Documents/netbeans/WebAlbums/trunk/WebAlbums3/WebAlbums3-ea/dist/gfdeploy/WebAlbums3-Service.jar for annotations in which a ServletContainerInitializer has expressed interest
>
> ```
> java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
> ```

Look like the JAR file is corrupted. Recompile/replace it. If you're FTP'ing this during deploying, take care that you send binary files as binary data, not as text data.

This can also be caused by the temp storage being full or not writable.

**Update**: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22java.util.zip.ZipException%3A+error+in+opening+zip+file%22+glassfish) learns me that this may also be JDK specific. Try upgrading JDK to the latest.

Comment: if you're talking about WebAlbums3-Service.jar, it can't be that, this is the main jar of my application, it's recompiled everyday, not transferred (netbeans/glassfish on the same computer); no space problem as well ...

Comment: For what it's worth, when I had a similar issue with SpringServer the jar was not corrupt.  Re-deploying would usually work.

Comment: I've got update-to-date JDKs, OpenJDK 1.0_18 on Ubuntu, HotSpot 1.6.0_17 on the Mac

Comment: That was my problem. A quick "file <jarfile.jar>" revealed that I had a text file and not a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the zip-file with winzip or 7zip? 
Can you open the file programmatically using ZipFile?
I am sure one of these questions will evaluate to false.

I had some strange zip errors some time ago related to special characters in the names of the contained file (where special means, non-ASCII characters).

Comment: It's not a zip file actually, the OP is using exploded deployment.

Answer (score 0):

> Having an '_' instead of a '.' is normal when you use exploded deployment (that's how the exploded artifact is supposed to be deployed)

It may be "normal" but GF is looking for a myEJB.jar file that's not there. There's only an exploded artefact, which then doesn't get deployed.

> The issue (both ZipException and already loaded EJBs) was resolved by extracting the EJB interfaces outside of where the implementation was defined (the implementation classes were loaded with each of the modules, hence the EJB exception)

Not sure I understand how this cures the above problem. My implementation class is a solitary message bean.

Comment: my feeling is that extracting the interfaces solved the problem because the 1st implementation didn't follow the 'guidelines' hence an unexpected behaviour, but maybe that was just a coincidence!